# What happens if I create a variable in python

Tags: python

I am new to python with some experience in Java.

```
class test:
    a = "123ss"
    def _init_(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def dosomething(self):
        print self.name
        b = "123"
        self.c = "aaa"
```

In the example above , a is a class variable, self.name is a instance variable. My question is that are b and c both instance variable or b and c only have the scope inside the method `dosomething`(thus not accessible by other methods)

Comment: Well, the `b` variable is a scope. But the `c` variable is now bound to the instance and will be accessible in future.

Comment: Unrelated: `__init__` is written with _double_ underscores, it won't do what you expect with single underscores.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this, I did not notice that :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b` is a local variable inside the method `dosomething`, it only exists there.

`self.c` is an attribute of the object `self`. Since that happens to be the instance, it is an instance attribute.

`self.name` is also looked up on `self`, but as the instance itself does not have that attribute, it is looked up on the class after trying the instance.

Finally, if you *assign* to `self.name`, then you *create an instance attribute*; `self.name` will have the new value afterwards, but only on that instance. `test.a` is the class attribute and it will be unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for great explanation!

Comment: Is there any difference between self.name and self.c since self.name is created in a special method __init__

Comment: No, it is completely irrelevant where things like this happen. `__init__` is only special in that it is called when the object is created, nothing else. You can `del` all the instance attributes later and create new ones, even from outside the class if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

First,the init funtion is `__init__` not `_init_` ,
Second, `c` is a instance variable, but only available after you run `instance.dosomething()`. 
Third, `b` will be only available in function scope.

Comment: the init funtion is 'init' with four underscores

Answer (score 1):

You could easily test this yourself, for example like this:

```
class test:
    a = "123ss"
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def dosomething(self):
        print(self.name)
        b = "123"
        self.c = "aaa"

for attr in ['name', 'a', 'b', 'c']: print hasattr(test, attr),
print

foo = test('bar')
for attr in ['name', 'a', 'b', 'c']: print hasattr(foo, attr),
print

foo.dosomething()
for attr in ['name', 'a', 'b', 'c']: print hasattr(foo, attr),
```

Outputs:

```
False True False False
True True False False
bar
True True False True
```

Note that `c` does not exist until you execute `dosomething()`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you have to use `self` explicitly to access instance variables. Otherwise you're accessing a local variable.